# HTML Form Submit to Google Calendar: Uncaught TypeError, Failed due to illegal value in property: 1

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-apps-script, forms

I believe I'm having a similar issue to [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27680509/google-script-run-not-working-uncaught-invalidargumenterror-failed-due-to-ille), but his solution isn't working for me.

I'm trying to have a Google App Script serve an HTML form that adds a Google Calendar event to my calendar.

#### Code.gs:

```js
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('form.html')
    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}

function scheduleEvent(array) {
  CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar().createEvent(array[0], array[1], array[2]);
  return 1;
}
```

#### form.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.6/paper/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.13.0/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.4/moment-timezone-with-data-2010-2020.min.js"></script>
    <style>body{padding:8px}</style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form class="form">
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Schedule a Meeting</legend>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="email">Your email:</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="you@gmail.com" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="eventName">What's the topic?</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="eventName" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="eventLocation">Where?</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="eventLocation" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="startTime">When? (EST)</label>
          <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" id="startTime" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="select">How Long?</label>
          <select class="form-control" id="duration" required>
            <option value="15">15 Minute Meeting</option>
            <option value="30" selected>30 Minute Meeting</option>
            <option value="60">60 Minute Meeting</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary submit" onClick="preprocessForm(this.form)">Submit</button>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function preprocessForm (form) {
      // check if they filled out their email, and set the variable if they did
      if (form.email.value) {
        var email = form.email.value;
      } else {
        alert("Please enter your email address, so I know who the appointment is with!");
        event.preventDefault();
        return 1;
      }
      // check if they filled out the event name, and set the variable if they did
      if (form.eventName.value) {
        var eventName = form.eventName.value;
      } else {
        alert("Please enter a name for the event!");
        event.preventDefault();
        return 1;
      }
      // set and format the event time and date, and grab the current time and date
      var currentTime = moment().tz('America/New_York');
      var startTime = moment(form.startTime.value).tz('America/New_York');
      var formattedStartTime = startTime.toDate();
      // html5 should stop the user from skipping filling out this section, but check anyway, just in case
      if (!form.startTime.value) {
        alert("Please enter a time for the event to occur!");
        event.preventDefault();
        return 1;
      }
      // we don't want people scheduling meetings in the past
      if (startTime.isBefore(currentTime)) {
        alert("Please pick a time that is in the future!");
        console.log('Start Time: ' + startTime);
        console.log('Current Time: ' + currentTime);
        event.preventDefault();
        return 1;
      }
      // check if they filled out the event location, and set the variable if they did
      if (form.eventLocation.value) {
        var eventLocation = form.eventLocation.value;
      } else {
        alert("Please enter an event location, so I know where to go!");
        event.preventDefault();
        return 1;
      }
      // it's not possible to skip the duration, since it's a dropdown that defaults to 30 minutes
      var duration = form.duration.value;
      var endTime = moment(startTime).add(duration, 'minutes');
      var formattedEndTime = endTime.toDate();

      var assembledDetails = [eventName, formattedStartTime, formattedEndTime];
      //toadd: , {location: eventLocation, guests: email}

      google.script.run.scheduleEvent(assembledDetails);

      // things to try and stop the redirect/refresh when pressing the submit button
      event.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm not having any luck. On submit, I get this error in the console:

[image]

Any advice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't send a date object in the array.  Property 1 is the second element in the array: `assembledDetails`

```
var assembledDetails = [eventName, formattedStartTime, formattedEndTime];
```

You could change the code to this:

```
formattedStartTime = formattedStartTime.toDateString();
formattedEndTime = formattedEndTime.toDateString();

var assembledDetails = [eventName, formattedStartTime, formattedEndTime];
```

Then you'd need to convert the date strings back to date objects in the server code.

Or:

You can strigify the object:

```
assembledDetails = JSON.stringify(assembledDetails);

google.script.run.scheduleEvent(assembledDetails);
```

And convert the object back in the server:

```
function scheduleEvent(array) {
  array = JSON.parse(array);
```

Quote from documentation:

> Requests fail if you attempt to pass a Date, Function, DOM element besides a form, or other prohibited type, including prohibited types inside objects or arrays.

[Apps Script documentation - Parameters and return values](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#parameters_and_return_values)

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer! I'll give it a shot.

You can't have a `date` object in an array? Fascinating. You can have other objects in an array... why not a date?

Comment: Just posted a link to the documentation.

Comment: Super helpful. Thanks so much!